# Why is mysqldump telling me I don't have enough space even though I have more than enough?

Tags: mysql, diskspace

I have two VMs, machine A which has a database I want a copy of and another, bigger machine B, I want to write the dump file to. Machine B has 30000 GB disk space and 64GB of RAM but when I run this simple dump command on Machine B I get receive `errno 28 on write` (indicating I do not have enough space). The file is initially written OK on machine B and I get the error after about 10 minutes.

```
mysqldump --host=<machine A> --port=3306 --user=<user> --password=<password> --databases <my_database> --hex-blob --master-data=1 --no-autocommit --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --single-transaction --quick > dumpfile.sql
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the user account you are using have some Quota that you are exceeding?

Comment: How much space does the origin VM have ?  Maybe its creating a temporary file there.

Comment: Double-check that your current working directory is in the filesystem in which you have the large free space: `df -h .`

Comment: In any case, this question should be on dba.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is for questions about code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was nothing to do with `mysqldump`. As the VM was brand new in gcloud I had to mount the disk and then run the mysqldump command from the directory I mounted it to - then I could avail of the space it had.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk